# No such app error with herokudns address

Tags: heroku, dns

I just upgraded my account on heroku to "hobby plan" and it gave me a new dns address, i was trying to access the dns address they given with the format mydomain.herokudns.com. and the page says No such app.

Answer (score 4):

I ask the support of heroku and they answered, that you can't access herokudns address you can only use it in your CNAME,.. you can access only your app through yourdomain.herokuapp.com .... so this is basically normal and nothing to worry about.